# What would this look like as pseudocode?

Tags: c++, graphics, vector, pseudocode

I'm trying to implement this: from https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.tinaja.com/glib/bezdist.pdf&pli=1

The following BASIC program uses the method of finding distance. The
program also searches for the minimum squared distance between points and
a curve.

```
REM BEZIER.BAS JIM 20DEC92 12:37
DATA 2,3,5,8,8,14,11,17,14,17,16,15,18,11,-1
DATA 2,10,5,12,8,11,11,8,14,6,17,5,19,10,-1
DATA 2,5,5,7,8,8,12,12,13,14,12,17,10,18,8,17,7,14,8,12,12,8,15,7,18,5,-1
OPEN "BEZIER.OUT" FOR OUTPUT AS #1
OPEN "BEZ.ps" FOR OUTPUT AS #2
CLS
psscale = 20
FOR example% = 1 TO 3
REDIM rawdata(32)
FOR I% = 0 TO 32
READ rawdata(I%)
IF rawdata(I%) < 0! THEN EXIT FOR
NEXT I%
n% = I% - 1
PRINT "Example "; example%; (n% + 1) \ 2; " points"
PRINT #1, ""
PRINT #1, "Example "; example%; (n% + 1) \ 2; " points"
PRINT #1, " #
x
y"
J% = 0
FOR I% = 0 TO n% STEP 2
J% = J% + 1
PRINT #1, USING "### ####.### ####.###"; J%; rawdata(I%); rawdata(I% + 1)
LPRINT USING "####.### ####.### 3 0 360 arc fill"; rawdata(I%) * psscale; rawdata(I% + 1) * psscale
PRINT #2, USING "####.### ####.### 3 0 360 arc fill"; rawdata(I%) * psscale; rawdata(I% + 1) * psscale
NEXT I%
x0 = rawdata(0)
y0 = rawdata(1)
x1 = rawdata(2)
y1 = rawdata(3)
x2 = rawdata(n% - 3)
y2 = rawdata(n% - 2)
x3 = rawdata(n% - 1)
y3 = rawdata(n%)
IF example% = 3 THEN
’special guess for loop
x1 = 8 * x1 - 7 * x0
y1 = 8 * y1 - 7 * y0
x2 = 8 * x2 - 7 * x3
y2 = 8 * y2 - 7 * y3
ELSE
x1 = 2 * x1 - x0
y1 = 2 * y1 - y0
x2 = 2 * x2 - x3
y2 = 2 * y2 - y3
END IF
GOSUB distance
LPRINT ".1 setlinewidth"
PRINT #2, ".1 setlinewidth"
GOSUB curveto
e1 = totalerror
FOR Retry% = 1 TO 6
PRINT
PRINT "Retry "; Retry%
PRINT #1, "Retry "; Retry%
PRINT #1, " x1
y1
x2
y2
error"
e3 = .5

x1a = x1
DO
x1 = x1 + (x1 - x0) * e3
GOSUB distance
e2 = totalerror
IF e2 = e1 THEN
EXIT DO
ELSEIF e2 > e1 THEN
x1 = x1a
e3 = -e3 / 3
IF ABS(e3) < .001 THEN EXIT DO
ELSE
e1 = e2
x1a = x1
END IF
LOOP
e3 = .5
y1a = y1
DO
y1 = y1 + (y1 - y0) * e3
GOSUB distance
e2 = totalerror
IF e2 = e1 THEN
EXIT DO
ELSEIF e2 > e1 THEN
y1 = y1a
e3 = -e3 / 3
IF ABS(e3) < .01 THEN EXIT DO
ELSE
e1 = e2
y1a = y1
END IF
LOOP
e3 = .5
x2a = x2
DO
x2 = x2 + (x2 - x3) * e3
GOSUB distance
e2 = totalerror
IF e2 = e1 THEN
EXIT DO
ELSEIF e2 > e1 THEN
x2 = x2a
e3 = -e3 / 3
IF ABS(e3) < .01 THEN EXIT DO
ELSE
e1 = e2
x2a = x2
END IF
LOOP
e3 = .5
y2a = y2
DO
y2 = y2 + (y2 - y3) * e3
GOSUB distance
e2 = totalerror
IF e2 = e1 THEN
EXIT DO
ELSEIF e2 > e1 THEN
y2 = y2a
e3 = -e3 / 3
IF ABS(e3) < .01 THEN EXIT DO

ELSE
e1 = e2
y2a = y2
END IF
LOOP
IF Retry% = 6 THEN
LPRINT "1 setlinewidth"
PRINT #2, "1 setlinewidth"
END IF
GOSUB curveto
NEXT Retry%
LPRINT "100 200 translate"
PRINT #2, "100 200 translate"
NEXT example%
LPRINT "showpage"
PRINT #2, "showpage"
CLOSE #1
CLOSE #2
END
’
Bezier:
x = a0 + u * (a1 + u * (a2 + u * a3))
y = b0 + u * (b1 + u * (b2 + u * b3))
dx4 = x - x4: dy4 = y - y4
dx = a1 + u * (2 * a2 + u * 3 * a3)
dy = b1 + u * (2 * b2 + u * 3 * b3)
z = dx * dx4 + dy * dy4
s = dx4 * dx4 + dy4 * dy4
RETURN
’
distance:
totalerror = 0!
a3 = (x3 - x0 + 3 * (x1 - x2)) / 8
b3 = (y3 - y0 + 3 * (y1 - y2)) / 8
a2 = (x3 + x0 - x1 - x2) * 3 / 8
b2 = (y3 + y0 - y1 - y2) * 3 / 8
a1 = (x3 - x0) / 2 - a3
b1 = (y3 - y0) / 2 - b3
a0 = (x3 + x0) / 2 - a2
b0 = (y3 + y0) / 2 - b2
FOR I% = 2 TO n% - 2 STEP 2
x4 = rawdata(I%)
y4 = rawdata(I% + 1)
stepsize = 2 / (n% + 1)
FOR u = -1! TO 1.01 STEP stepsize
GOSUB Bezier
IF s = 0! THEN u1 = u: z1 = z: s1 = s: EXIT FOR
IF u = -1! THEN u1 = u: z1 = z: s1 = s
IF s < s1 THEN u1 = u: z1 = z: s1 = s
NEXT u
IF s1 <> 0! THEN
u = u1 + stepsize
IF u > 1! THEN u = 1! - stepsize
DO
GOSUB Bezier
IF s = 0! THEN EXIT DO
IF z = 0! THEN EXIT DO
u2 = u
z2 = z
temp = z2 - z1
IF temp <> 0! THEN
u = (z2 * u1 - z1 * u2) / temp

ELSE
u = (u1 + u2) / 2!
END IF
IF u > 1! THEN
u = 1!
ELSEIF u < -1! THEN
u = -1!
END IF
IF ABS(u - u2) < .0001 THEN EXIT DO
u1 = u2
z1 = z2
LOOP
END IF
totalerror = totalerror + s
NEXT I%
PRINT totalerror;
PRINT #1, USING "####.### ####.### ####.### ####.### ######.###"; x1; y1; x2; y2; totalerror
RETURN
’
curveto:
LPRINT USING "####.### ####.### moveto"; x0 * psscale; y0 * psscale
PRINT #2, USING "####.### ####.### moveto"; x0 * psscale; y0 * psscale
F$ = "####.### ####.### ####.### ####.### ####.### ####.### curveto stroke"
LPRINT USING F$; x1 * psscale; y1 * psscale; x2 * psscale; y2 * psscale; x3 * psscale; y3 * psscale
PRINT #2, USING F$; x1 * psscale; y1 * psscale; x2 * psscale; y2 * psscale; x3 * psscale; y3 * psscale
RETURN
```

I want to implement it in c++ because I'm trying to get my algorithm to best fit beziers from points.

What would the above look like in pseudo-code or c / c++?
thanks

Comment: If you just want a Bezier curve, just look up the algorithm for Bezier curves, don't try to reverse engineer some primitive language that was designed to be harder for humans to read so it was easier for machines to read.

Comment: That's not pseudo-code. That's apparently fully functional code

Comment: No I need fitting which basically finds control points from points which this does

Comment: klez: AVR Assembler is easier on the eyes than BASIC :(

Comment: @Skurmedel, I've never seen AVR Assembler, but I bet you're right :)

Comment: At least there are no GOTO's. Indent it properly, and it won't probably be that bad any more.

Comment: My first language, how I've missed you.

Comment: Are you asking for a line-by-line translation? I don't think it is particularly hard, but perhaps you'd rather ask about particular commands you don't understand (e.g I have no idea what the exclamation marks mean after some literals, probably some irrelevant detail of the language?)

Comment: @UncleBens I think `!` means "float" like a trailing `f` in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach here is to split the code bit by bit and do minor refactorings until it's in a usable state. Data can be changed into global variables at first.

Then start taking small chunks of the code and turning them into functions. At first they'll just use a bunch of global data. As you rewrite the pieces into C++ things will become more clear.

Once you have most of the code built out functionally, then you can start refactoring the variables. The goal would be to remove all the global non-const data and have all the working data be locals. const values can remain namespace level initialized data.

Finally once you have it procedure-based, you can decide if it's worth the effort to encapsulate the work into objects and methods. Depending on how long the program needs to be maintained grouping the data and methods may be a good long-term step.